# how to truncate a number with a decimal point into a int? what's the function for this?

Tags: c

The problem occurs when I do a division operation. I would like to know who to truncate a number with a decimal point into a whole number such as 2,  4, 67.

Comment: What language? What environment?

Comment: I think tag identifies it as C. Environment should not matter.

Comment: "when I do a division operation" --> is the division using integer operands or floating-point ones?  A good answer depends on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It truncates automatically is you assign value to "int" variable:

```
int c;    
c = a/b;
```

Or you can cast like this:

```
c = (int) (a/b);
```

This truncates it even if c is defined as float or double.

Usually truncation is not the best (depends what you want to achieve of course). Usually result is rounded like this:

```
c= round(a/b,0);
```

is more intelligent because rounds result properly. If you use linux, you can easily get reference with "man round" about exact data types etc.

Comment: In `c = (int) a/b;`, the cast applies to `a`, not to `a/b`. If you want to cast `a/b`, you need parentheses: `c = (int)(a/b);`.

Comment: The `lrint` family of functions are possibly more suitable, as they round the value just as `round`, but returns an integer instead of a float.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this stupid mistake now to avoid someone repeating mistake.

Comment: "`c = (int) (a/b);` This truncates it even if c is defined as float or double." is subject to that range limitation of `int` as outside that,the result is _undefined behavior_.  `c = trunc(a/b);` does not have that problem.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel @KeithThompson when I put suppose `int a = 5` `int b = 9` and `float c = (float)a/b;`, it displays 0.555556 which is intended. But `float c = (float) (a/b);` has the truncated result of 0.000000. Why is it that when this joint casting works on int but not float?

Comment: @mr.loop Operator precedence. The cast binds more tightly than the division operator. `(float)a/b)` is equivalent to `((float)a) / b`; it converts `a` to `float`, then the division causes `b` to be implicitly converted to `float`, so it's a floating-point division. `(float)(a/b)` does an integer division on `a` and `b`, yielding `0`, which is then converted from `int` to `float` by the cast. In almost all cases, every (sub)expression has a type that's determined by the expression itself, not by the context in which it appears.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `trunc()` function defined in `math.h`. It will remove fractional part and will return nearest integer not larger than the given number.

This is how it is defined:

```
double trunc(double x);
```

Below is how you can use it:

```
double a = 18.67;
double b = 3.8;
int c = trunc(a/b);
```

You can check `man trunc` on Linux to get more details about this function. As pointed out in previous answers, you can cast division result to integer or it will automatically be truncated if assigned to integer but if you were interested to know about a C function which does the job then `trunc()` is the one.

Comment: Best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Manually or implicitly casting from a floating-point type to an integral type causes automatic truncation toward zero. Keep in mind that if the integral type is not sufficiently large to store the value, overflow will occur. If you simply need to print the value with everything past the decimal point truncated, use `printf()`:

```
printf("%.0f", floor(float_val));
```

As Tõnu Samuel has pointed out, that `printf()` invocation will actually round the floating-point parameter by default.

Comment: This %.0f is not truncated but rounded as much I know.

Comment: Using `trunc()` to truncate makes more sense that `floor()`.  Using `truncf()` even makes more sense for a `float float_val`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = (int)ceilf(myFloat );
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );
int result = (int)floor(myFloat);

float result = ceilf(myFloat );
float result = roundf(myFloat );
float result = floor(myFloat);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: As OP asks "how to truncate a number ...", I recommend to add  `truncf()`.