# How to display a float with no decimal digits in C

Tags: c

I want to print a float with no decimal digits. I know I can use another variable like int and make it the same, but I wanted to avoid that if there is something simpler (like %02f but to limit instead of being at least two digits long).

If there is no way then I'll use a variable int.

Thank you

Comment: There is probably a cleaner way but I would do `printf("%d\n", (int)myfloat);`

Comment: This information is available in all the format string documentation for `printf`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to truncate a number with a decimal point into a int? what's the function for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184326/how-to-truncate-a-number-with-a-decimal-point-into-a-int-whats-the-function-fo)

Comment: To be fair, the format string documentation is not the easiest to digest if you're not that experienced... which based on this question, I think is a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want something like

```
printf("%.0f\n", my_float);
```

This will tell `printf` to include 0 decimal places of precision (you can, of course, use other values as well).

Comment: Note that this performs rounding. If desiring to just truncate then cast to int.